# Choosing correct Django delete view approach

Tags: django

I'm working on Django website and I have problem in figuring out correct/good way to handle delete view. From what I found out there are two ways to approach it:

1

```
class ObjectDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = Object
    def get_success_url(self):
        objectid = self.kwargs['object_id']
        object = Object.objects.get(id = objectid)
        container = object.container
        containerid = container.id
        url = reverse('Containers:showContainerContent', args=[containerid])
        return url 
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Object, pk=self.kwargs['object_id'])
```

2

```
def objectDelete(request, object_id):
    object = Object.objects.get(id = object_id)
    container = object.container
    containerid = container.id
    url = reverse('Containers:showContainerContent', args=[containerid])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

From what I can tell both are doing exactly the same thing - once object is deleted present user with page under Containers:showContainerContent.

The big difference I am experiencing is error I am getting when running unit test for this (simple call of the website and check of response code). With option 1 I end up getting error

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: ContainerApp/object_confirm_delete.html
```

Which I understand - I don't have this template, this is default template for DeleteView, hence error is correct. The thing is I don't want to have any extra page. Just redirect user and that's it.

Also, I tested changing `return url` to `return HttpResponseRedirect(url)` in option 1, but result is the same.

What should I do here? Should I just continue with option 2? What are or might be the drawbacks for this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major difference between two class based delete view and function based view (the way you declared it).

**CBV** accepts `get`, `post` and `delete` http methods. When you send a `get` request to class based view, it does not delete the object. Instead it renders template with object to be deleted in context. This is basically used to have confirmation. For example you can send a get request and it will render a template with text "Do you really want to delete?" or "Please confirm blah blah..". And if you send a `post` or `delete` request, it will actually delete the object and redirect to next page.

**FBV**, on the other hand, give you full control over what you want to do. And as you declared it, it will accept any request type and delete the object and redirect to next page because you have not done any request type check in your view which is not a great idea IMHO. You should not allow deletion on get requests. They should be idempotent. There are plenty of otherthings that CBV provides. For example in case the object does not exist your FBV will crash. CBV, on contrary, will return proper 404 response if object does not exist.

So I think there is no bad in using FBV, but make is strong and secure enough that it handles every case (what if object does not exist?, what about confirmation?, `GET` should be idempotent only allow deletion with post? etc etc). Or simply use CBV.